# Convolution of a mirrored signal

Tags: discrete-signals, convolution

I want to compute the following convolution sum:
$$r_h[k] = h[k] * h^{*}[-k]$$
To do that first let $g[k] = h^{*}[-k]$
\begin{equation}
r_h[k] = \sum_n h[n]g[k-n]
\end{equation}

where $g[k-n] = h^{*}[n-k]$ according to my definition. Then the result is:
\begin{equation}
r_h[k] = \sum_n h[n]h^{*}[n-k]
\end{equation}

This derivation appears to be incorrect since the correct result is:
\begin{equation}
r_h[k] = \sum_n h[n]h^{*}[n+k]
\end{equation}

Can you tell me why my calculation is incorrect? What is the best to convolve the mirrored signals?

Comment: There's a typo in your question: the *correct* result (note your first result is also correct, see my answer) is $r_h[k] = \sum_{n}h^*[n]h[n+k]$

Answer (score 3):

#### First,

> This derivation appears to be incorrect since the correct result is:
> \begin{equation} r_h[k] = \sum_n h[n]h^{*}[n+k] \end{equation}

There's a mistake or a typo here. The correct result should be $$r_h[k]=\sum_{n}h^*[n]h[n+k]$$

---

#### Answer

Your calculation is correct: you're computing the [autocorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) of $h$ at lag $k$, which, for signals with finite energy, is defined as:
$$r_{hh}[k] \triangleq \sum_{n}h[n]h^*[n-k] \triangleq \sum_{n}h^*[n]h[n+k]$$

---

**EDIT: Why both definitions are equivalent**

Let's start with the more common definition of autocorrelation for a finite energy signal $h[k]$:
$$r_{hh}[k]\triangleq \sum_{n}h^*[n]h[n+k]$$

Let $l$ = $n+k$, then:
$$r_{hh}[k]\triangleq \sum_{l}h^*[l-k]h[l]$$
Substitute $n$ for $l$ and permute the product:
$$r_{hh}[k]\triangleq \sum_{n}h^*[n-k]h[n] = \sum_{n}h[n]h^*[n-k]$$

---

**EDIT #2: Why both definitions are equivalent**

Another nice way of showing why both definitions are equivalent is using the well-documented result for the cross-correlation of two finite energy signals $h_1[k]$ and $h_2[k]$ (you can find the proof anywhere, it's similar to my first edit):
$$r_{h_1h_2}[k] = r^*_{h_1h_2}[-k]$$
For autocorrelation, set $h_1 = h_2 = h$, and this becomes:
$$r_{hh}[k] = r^*_{hh}[-k]$$
with $$r_{hh}[k] \triangleq \sum_{n}h^*[n]h[n+k]\tag{1}$$
$$r^*_{hh}[-k] \triangleq \sum_{n}h[n]h^*[n-k]\tag{2}$$
$(1)$ is the standard definition, and $(2)$ comes from taking the complex conjugate of $(1)$ and time-reversing. Remember that for two complex numbers $A$ and $B$, $(AB)^* = A^*B^*$

Comment: Why does $h^{*}[n-k] = h^{*}[n+k]$ hold?

Comment: @lordvoldemort It doesn't. There's a typo in your question. I edited my answer to show why both definitions are equivalent